# Ragged2e causing build failure

Tags: formatting, ragged2e

The following Latex document shows this equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{
  parskip % Makes formatting nicer
}
\begin{document}
$\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))
\\ = \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Latex screenshot]

I'm very happy with how this looks.

However, when I use the ragged2e package (by uncommenting the usepackage statement above) Latex fails to build:

[image: Latex errors]

How can I make this work with ragged2e, without changing the appearance of my equation?

I've tried moving the `\\` to the end of line 7 but saw the same errors.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. When I remove the \\, I get no errors.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos For me this puts the whole equation on one line. I'm happy with how the equation looks now and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: using inlin emath here doesn't look nice I'd use `multline` from `amsmath` which will use display math and id explicitly designed to show a single equation breaking over a line

Answer (score 4):

If it's all one equation, you should assure that LaTeX won't insert a page break between the lines. One way to do so is by encasing the material in an `aligned` environment.

Do note that this concern is quite independent of whether or not the `ragged2e` package is loaded (with or without the `document` option).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{parskip} % probably not needed if 'ragged2e' package is loaded with 'document' option

\begin{document}
$\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))\\
&= \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\tfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inline math uses a compressed style so that when used mid-paragraph it does not disturb the regular baseline spacing of the surrounding text. It isn't really suitable for a self-standing math display.

The amsmath package provides a range of multi-line math environments depending on teh effect that you want to achieve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% always load for mathematicat documents
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{
  parskip % Makes formatting ---nicer--- different
}
\begin{document}


\subsection*{inline}
$\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))$\\
${}= \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$

\subsection*{multline}
\begin{multline*}
\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))\\
 = \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{multline*}

\subsection*{multline (alt)}
\begin{multline*}
\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c)) ={}\\
 \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{multline*}


\subsection*{align}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))\\
&= \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{align*}


\subsection*{align2}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))={}\\
&\lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{align*}

\subsection*{align3}
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c)) \\
&= \lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{align*}

\subsection*{align4}
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c)) ={}\\
&\lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{
  parskip % Makes formatting nicer
}
\begin{document}
$\lim_{x \to c}(f(x) - f(c))$

$=\lim_{x \to c}(x - c)\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It obfuscates the fact that this is all one equation, but it is a nice simple solution +1